# Tensorflow tf.data AUTOTUNE

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I was reading the TF performance guide for Data Loading section. For prefetch it says,

> The tf.data API provides a software pipelining mechanism through the
>   tf.data.Dataset.prefetch transformation, which can be used to decouple
>   the time when data is produced from the time when data is consumed. In
>   particular, the transformation uses a background thread and an
>   internal buffer to prefetch elements from the input dataset ahead of
>   the time they are requested. The number of elements to prefetch should
>   be equal to (or possibly greater than) the number of batches consumed
>   by a single training step. You could either manually tune this value,
>   or set it to tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE which will prompt the
>   tf.data runtime to tune the value dynamically at runtime.

What is AUTOTUNE doing internally? Which algorithm, heuristics are being applied?

Additionally, in practice, what kind of manual tuning is done?

Answer (score 15):

`tf.data` builds a performance model of the input pipeline and runs an optimization algorithm to find a good allocation of its CPU budget across all parameters specified as `AUTOTUNE`. While the input pipeline is running, `tf.data` tracks the time spent in each operation, so that these times can be fed into the optimization algorithm.

The [OptimizationOptions](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/experimental/OptimizationOptions?version=stable) object gives some control over how autotune will behave.

Comment: this doesn't say anything about `AUTOTUNE` :/

Comment: It does mention AUTOTUNE. Whichever dataset pre-fetches are set to AUTOTUNE are monitored and optimized. However I agree it does not fully answer the OPs question as to what heuristics it uses internally. The associated TF documentation is weak

Answer (score 4):

The authors provide details about the `AUTOTUNE` in their vldb paper https://vldb.org/pvldb/vol14/p2945-klimovic.pdf. Refer section 3.3.2.

[image]